# Extract attr values from Element

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i have below Scenario Where function returns HTML element and stored it into a variable.

```
var Element = ABC();
```

Where ABC is function.

Element has Value as

```
<select id='2' style='width:80px;position:absolute;'/>
```

This var type doesn't contains any html,inner-HTML or outer-HTML functions so that i can extract attr values. Element could be any element its not restricted only SELECT.
How can i do this in jquery?

Comment: Is `ABC()` returning an HTML element, or is it returning a string?

Comment: its Returning String..

Comment: `$(Element).attr('id')`...something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the string into HTML with jQuery:

```
var $Element = $(Element);
var style = $Element.attr('style');
var id = $Element.attr('id');
```